# How to dynamically add a click handler to an li with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a click handler to an `li` that is added to the DOM through jQuery.  I thought this is the way you did it:

```
jQuery('.deleteUpload').on('click', '.deleteUpload', function() {
    var strDocId = jQuery(this).prop('id');
    //if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this resource') == true) {
        $.post('/study-clubs/meetings/delete-upload', {strDocId : strDocId},
            function(objData){
                console.log(objData);
            }
        );
        jQuery('li#' + strDocId).remove();
    //}

    return false;
});
```

Here is my markup:

```
<li class="pdf deleteLi" id="<?php echo $this->escape($this->objDocRow->id); ?>">
   <label><input type="radio" name="documents[1]" value="0" /> Pre-Meeting</label> &nbsp;
   <label><input type="radio" name="documents[1]" value="1" /> Post-Meeting</label> &nbsp;
   <label><input type="radio" name="documents[1]" value="2" checked /> Do Not Use</label> &nbsp;
   <a href="#" class="deleteUpload" id="2">Delete</a> &nbsp;
   <a href="/..."><?php echo substr($this->escape($this->objDocRow->doc_title), 0, -4); ?></a>
</li>
```

I want to delete the `li` when you click on the `a` tag with a class of `deleteUpload`. What am I doing wrong?  When I click on it, I'm taken to the top of the page.  I also tried `deleteLi` instead of `deleteUpload` in the jQuery, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try `jQuery(document).on('click', '.deleteUpload', function() {`

Comment: You can use .bind() and .unBind() http://api.jquery.com/bind/ to add/remove click handlers.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall: `on()` is the new, cooler way to attach event handlers these days. `bind()` will soon join the deprecated methods like `live()` ;).

Comment: Thanks, jtheman.  I knoew there was something I was forgetting.

Comment: I really dig .on() @Matt, Thanks for the heads up on deprecation!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the first line to:

```
jQuery('.deleteLi').on('click', '.deleteUpload', function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to have the second selector. With it jquery will look for a child of .deleteUpload that has the class deleteUpload.

```
jQuery('.deleteUpload').on('click', function() {
    var strDocId = jQuery(this).prop('id');
    //if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this resource') == true) {
        $.post('/study-clubs/meetings/delete-upload', {strDocId : strDocId},
            function(objData){
                console.log(objData);
            }
        );
        jQuery('li#' + strDocId).remove();
    //}

    return false;
});
```